# Statistical Chances Calculation

Tags: statistics

I have a function with 3 variables that can be modified based on random chance.  For example a random number is picked from a range of 100, if random number is in range of 0 to 9, A is modified (10%), B is 11-30 (20%), C is 31 to 35 (5%).

I have rewritten this function so that the 3 variables all have a chance to be modified in the same call (random number is generated 3 times).  What number ranges would I give to each variable if I wanted the overall chance of each variable being selected to be the same as the previous behaviour?

Comment: I don't understand the problem / question.

Comment: Welcome. It's not clear if you are asking for programming help, or for mathematical help. If the latter please consider reposting your question on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write a quick Java app to answer my question:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class Main {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;

        System.out.println("old: ");

        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
            int rand = random();
            if (rand < 10) {
                a++;
                continue;
            }

            if (rand >= 10 && rand < 20) {
                b++;
                continue;
            }

            if (rand >= 20 && rand < 30) {
                c++;
                continue;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("a= " + a);
        System.out.println("b= " + b);
        System.out.println("c= " + c);
        int total = a+b+c;
        System.out.println("total " + total);

        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;

        System.out.println("new: ");

        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
            int rand = random();
            if (rand < 10) {
                a++;

            }
            rand = random();
            if (rand >= 10 && rand < 20) {
                b++;

            }
            rand = random();
            if (rand >= 20 && rand < 30) {
                c++;
            }
        }


        System.out.println("a= " + a);
        System.out.println("b= " + b);
        System.out.println("c= " + c);
        total = a+b+c;
        System.out.println("total " + total);
    }

    public static int random() {
        return (int)(Math.random() * 100);
    }
}
```

and the results between "new" and "old" were very similar:

```
old:
a= 1000
b= 1005
c= 1001
total 3006
new:
a= 949
b= 1023
c= 999
total 2971
```

So as it turns out, no difference at all.